# Signature Chains: Ensuring Authenticity and Trust

Tags: public-key, keys, certificates

I'm studying for an exam and came across this question:

> When an electronic signature of a message claimed to be produced by
> Alice is verified we typically verify (at least the first time):
>
> 1. that the public key belongs to Alice by verifying that it has been signed (along with additional information) by a certificate authority
>    (CA) who we trust (such a signature is called a "certificate"),
> 2. that the verification algorithm accepts the signature as valid for the message.
>
> Suppose that you receive public keys pk<sub>A</sub>, pk<sub>X</sub>, and
> pk<sub>Y</sub> and signatures s<sub>A</sub>, s<sub>X</sub>, and
> s<sub>Y</sub> such that:
>
> - Vf<sub>pk<sub>A</sub></sub>(s<sub>A</sub>,m)=1
> - Vf<sub>pk<sub>X</sub></sub>(s<sub>X</sub>,"Alice's public key is pk<sub>A</sub>")=1
> - Vf<sub>pk<sub>Y</sub></sub>(s<sub>Y</sub>,"X's public key is pk<sub>X</sub>")=1
>
> where *Vf* denotes the verification algorithm of the signature scheme.
> You know that *pk<sub>Y</sub>* belongs to the certificate authority
> *Y*. Is this is enough to be confident that Alice signed *m*?

I'm a bit confused but I'm leaning towards a 'no'. The trust in the ownership of pk<sub>A</sub> as Alice's public key is based solely on the endorsement by X and not on a direct verification by the CA. If X is malicious or compromised, pk<sub>A</sub> and s<sub>A</sub> could theoretically belong to someone else, such as Eve, and not Alice.

Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would concur with your interpretation, although the question is a little vague.

When the question says that we trust $Y$ does this mean that we trust $Y$ only to sign messages that are true? Or that it believes to be true to the best of its knowledge?

In either case there is nothing in the statement "$X$'s public key is $pk_X$" that should makes us think that $X$ is a similarly trustworthy individual. In the real world additional transfer of trust should be explicit and the signed statement from $Y$ would be to the effect of "$X$'s public key is $pk_X$ and they may act as a delegated authority on my part" which we would reasonably assume means the same level of trust and truthfulness can be ascribed to signed statements by $X$. In the absence of a specific delegation of trust we should not trust $X$'s signed statements to be true.

Comment: Thank you for your response! After posting my question, I came across a similar discussion on [post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/55332/115322) which seems to touch on the same topic. Specifically, one of the [replies](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/55343/115322) suggests that if Y is a CA and we 'trust' them to perform their duties correctly, then we should logically also trust Alice's key, implying a 'yes' answer to my question. Do you think that that argument is invalid? @daniel

Comment: @user1: the conclusion in the question is correct: we should NOT trust that "Alice signed m". The answer correctly explains why: we have no reason to trust X when they signed "Alice's public key is pkA". Things could be different if Y had signed "X's public key is pkX and I hereby delegate to X my authority of designating which key is who's. X will sign messages to this effect with their private key matching pkX". There are options in X.509 certificates for just that sort of delegation.

Comment: @user1: This is more in the realms of cybersecurity policy than cryptography, but that comment on the other question is not in-keeping with the modern [zero trust principle of least privilege](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/access-management/principle-of-least-privilege/).